# How to upload and create a specific directory in openshift?

Tags: java, openshift

I am working on a Java web application.There is a section for file uploading.So far I have used my LocalFileSystem.Now I have deployed my application successfully on openshift.I want to create some folder in openshift hosting like /MyFile and save all myFiles in that location.But So far I have not find any way to create a folder in openshift java hosting

How can I do this?